# SonarQube Analysis Failing

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

I am trying to add a sonarQube(5.6.3) to my Jenkins. SonarQube is reachable from my Jenkins but getting this error while analysis:

```
[ERROR] sonar.binaries and sonar.libraries are not supported since version 4.0 of sonar-java-plugin, please use sonar.java.binaries and sonar.java.libraries instead
```

Though, I am not specifying sonar-java-plugin in my project pom, I tried these without success:
1. updated sonar-maven-plugin in pom
2. replaced  with  in pom
Please help me with it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide more information. What Jenkins version are you using? Did you install the SonarQube Plugin by searching it in the manage plugins tab?

Comment: Also add java pluggin version

Comment: Jenkins version: 2.7.20. Yes, I installed SonarQube Plugin

Comment: @humblebee verify why do you use sonar.binaries and sonar.libraries ?no need in your project. Tell us.